# Converter in windows 8 app not supported

Tags: c#

So I have a class called ImageConverter but I can't import it to my xaml.
I thought it was `<converter x:key="converter"/>` but it doesn't exist.

Am I doing something wrong or did I miss a reference?

```
class ImageConverter : IValueConverter
{

    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
    {
        String picNaam = (String)value;
        String pad = "c:/documents" + picNaam;
        return pad;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Converters are supported in windows 8 metro apps. Your *declaration is incorrect*.

It should be like this:

`<converter:ImageConverter x:Key="converter"/>`

where ***converter*** is namespace where ImageConverter is defined. Declare it at root level:

```
xmlns:converter="clr-namespace:ActualNamespace"
```

Also you need to make the class ***public***.

```
public class ImageConverter : IValueConverter
```

Comment: Ahh right thanks! I totally messed that up. However, I get an error message now: Unknown type 'ImageConverter' in XML namespace 'clr-namespace:AppFestival.DataModels;assembly=AppFestival, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null

Comment: Keep only assembly name not fully qualified path. `clr-namespace:AppFestival.DataModels;assembly=AppFestival` is sufficient.

Comment: I only have: xmlns:dm="clr-namespace:AppFestival.DataModels" , that's all

Comment: Make class `public`. You are missing access modifier. Updated in answer.

Comment: Thanks for you answer, but it was already public and not working

Comment: Make sure all projects are build properly. Otherwise your code looks perfect.

Comment: Just noticed it's "using:" instead of "clr-namespace" in wpf, thanks for you time and answers!